# Tomcat Runtime exception help: ... JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory'

Tags: java, tomcat, java-17

Context:

I'm developing a piece of java code that is supposed to be running within a vendor app server running on tomcat (with startup.xml). The vendor code I can't touch, but they expose a framework such that we can drop plugins into their platform to create custom implementations of their interfaces they expose. As part of their version upgrade, they move from java 11 to java 17 and we're experiencing a regression (error below).

We ensured our maven pom.xml is targeting java 17 and that the fasterxml libraries are all consistent...

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I noticed in the vendor's tomcat lib folder, they do have very old fasterxml libraries of 2.9.8 and I noticed that it does not have TokenStreamFactory in their javadoc for that version. Unfortunately, I can't alter that as it's vendor code/black box. I can only work within the confines of the plugin I create and drop into their specified folder. I can alter the startup.xml but it's sort of "at my own risk".

```
ERROR: RuntimeException encountered attempting to send message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producerException in thread "ordermessageadapter" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
        at com.vendor.xyz.conn.kafka.KafkaTopicSenderFactory.createAdapter(KafkaTopicSenderFactory.java:39)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at com.vendor.plugin.APIInvocationHandler.invoke(APIInvocationHandler.java:62)
        at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy166.createAdapter(Unknown Source)
        at com.vendor.messageadapter.EndPoint$MySenderBufferThread.run(EndPoint.java:134)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:442)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:292)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:319)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:304)
        at com.xyz.connection.manager.KafkaBuilder.producerCreation(KafkaBuilder.java:56)
        at com.xyz.connection.manager.KafkaBuilder.connect(KafkaBuilder.java:52)
        at com.vendor.xyz.conn.kafka.KafkaTopicSenderAdapter.<init>(KafkaTopicSenderAdapter.java:49)
        at com.vendor.xyz.conn.kafka.KafkaTopicSenderFactory.createAdapter(KafkaTopicSenderFactory.java:36)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<init>(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:157)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.configureClientProperties(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:83)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.configure(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:56)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.configure(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:378)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0
 [in thread "MyCode"]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper.builder(JsonMapper.java:114)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.utils.JacksonMapper.<clinit>(JacksonMapper.java:27)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.<clinit>(RestService.java:155)
        ... 19 more
```

I've double checked that my java plugin build has no other versions of fasterxml besides 2.13.2. Any idea on how else to troubleshoot or approach this? I feel strongly that it has to do with the change of the tomcat app going from java 11 to 17... so I'm hoping perhaps it's something I can tweak in startup.xml somehow. I am guessing when the app starts up, somehow the older fasterxml version (2.9.8) is somehow interferring.

Update: Tried shading but unable to get my project to reference/import them.

I see the shaded classes created for a new project (named "common") and the jar wraps fasterxml.

In my other plugin projct, XYZ, which depends on these shades, it's not able to find, despite the dependency:

import my.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

The XYZ pom:

```
<groupId>test-common</groupId>
<artifactId>test-common</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
```

Plugins

```
└───XYZ.jar

└───common.jar

     └───jackson*2.13.2
```

How do I get XYZ to see the shaded items?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a classic case of ["jar hell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell), where different parts of your application and its dependencies require different versions of the same library.
In your case, your plugin requires `fasterxml.jackson` version `2.13.2`, but the vendor application bundled with Tomcat uses an older version (`2.9.8`), leading to compatibility issues and the runtime exception you have encountered. The classpath precedence determines that the older version of the library is loaded instead of the version your plugin requires.

```bash
Tomcat
└───lib
    └───jackson-*-2.9.8 (Vendor libs, older version)
    └───other vendor libs
Plugins
└───your-plugin.jar
    └───jackson-*-2.13.2 (Your libs, required version)
```

If possible, modify your plugin to use a custom class loader that prioritizes your bundled libraries over the ones provided by the vendor application. But that might not be supported directly by the vendor's framework.

Since you mentioned you can modify the `startup.xml` at your own risk, you could try to adjust the classpath to prefer loading classes from your plugin's jar file before the vendor's libraries. That could involve specifying class loader properties, such as `parentFirst="false"` for your plugin's context. However, this might not be feasible or reliable, depending on how the vendor application and Tomcat manage class loading.

Instead, you can use [Maven's Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to create a shaded (or uber) jar of your plugin, which relocates your specific version of the Jackson libraries to a different package namespace. That way, your plugin will use its version of Jackson without conflict with the vendor's version. However, this requires careful handling to make sure *all* references to the relocated classes are updated accordingly.

As an example, your `pom.xml` would be:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>your.custom.package.jackson</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

That setup will relocate all `com.fasterxml.jackson` classes to `your.custom.package.jackson`, allowing your plugin to use its version of Jackson without conflicting with the vendor's version. You will  update your code to use the new package names accordingly.

Assuming you have configured the Maven Shade Plugin in your `pom.xml` to relocate `com.fasterxml.jackson` to `com.mycompany.shaded.jackson`:

#### Before Shading

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        try {
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

##### After Adjustment

```java
import com.mycompany.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mycompany.shaded.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Notice the import statements have changed to the shaded package
        com.mycompany.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new com.mycompany.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        try {
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (com.mycompany.shaded.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

> Tried shading, but was unable to get my project to reference/import them.
>
> I see the shaded classes created for a new project (named "common") and the jar wraps fasterxml.
>
> In my other plugin project, XYZ, which depends on these shades, it's not able to find, despite the dependency:
>
> ```
> import my.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
> ```
>
> The XYZ pom:
>
> ```xml
>     <groupId>test-common</groupId>
>     <artifactId>test-common</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0</version>
>     <scope>compile</scope>
> ```
>
> ```
> Plugins
>     └───XYZ.jar
>     └───common.jar    
>          └───jackson*2.13.2
> ```
>
> How do I get XYZ to see the shaded items?

If you have successfully created a shaded JAR in one project (`common`) that relocates and bundles the Jackson libraries, but are having trouble using those shaded classes in a dependent project (`XYZ`), there might be an issue with how the dependency is declared or with how the projects are structured.

First, make sure the dependency declaration in your `XYZ` project's `pom.xml` file correctly points to your `common` project. Based on your description, it seems there might be a mismatch or an error in the way you have declared the dependency. Here is what the dependency declaration should look like:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>test-common</groupId> <!-- That should match the groupId of the common project -->
        <artifactId>test-common</artifactId> <!-- That should match the artifactId of the common project -->
        <version>1.0</version> <!-- That should match the version of the common project -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Make sure the `groupId`, `artifactId`, and `version` in the dependency declaration exactly match those specified in the `common` project's `pom.xml`.

And check the shaded JAR (`common.jar`) is properly installed in your local Maven repository or is available in your organization's Maven repository if you are using one. If you have not done this yet, you can install the JAR to your local repository by running `mvn install` from the directory containing the `common` project.

In the `XYZ` project, when you try to import the shaded classes, the import paths must match the relocated package paths specified during the shading process in the `common` project. Based on your example, imports should look like this:

```java
import my.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
```

Make sure the package prefix (`my.shaded`) matches the `<shadedPattern>` you specified in the `common` project's `pom.xml` during the shading process.

Try from the command line first, with a `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package` to make sure Maven picks up the changes correctly.

Comment: Tried shading but unable to get my project to reference/import them.

I see the shaded classes created for a new project (named "common") and the jar wraps fasterxml.

In my other plugin projct, XYZ, which depends on these shades, it's not able to find, despite the dependency:

import my.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

The XYZ pom:

        <groupId>test-common</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>

How do I get XYZ to see the shaded items?

Comment: Please see updated question for better format of my question